# Comma and no period in dollar price

Tags: paypal, number-formatting

When I make my add to cart-button, the price (in dollars) is displayed 18,00, and not 18.00, which makes some customers think that the price is eighteen hundred dollars instead of eighteen dollars. This is the code I use:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="PXUZGKZW3BP6Q">
  <input type="image" src="http://www.mdna-games.com/cart.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I've put "lc=EN" under advanced properties to make sure that the page is always displayed in English, but still the price is not displayed according to English/American standards.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you followed the instructions [here](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/mc/mc_wa-outside)?  It says that the code for United States Dollars is `USD`.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't help. Besides, if the currency_code is omitted, the default currency will be U.S. Dollars. And the currency IS no doubt USD on my buttons, even the dollar sign is displayed before the prices. The problem just that it uses a comma instead of a period in the price.

Answer (score 1):

The button is paying an account that happens to be in a locale that uses a comma rather than a period to indicate decimals.

The solution is to pass a locale code that uses a period as desired.  For instance:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="PXUZGKZW3BP6Q">
  <input type="image" src="http://www.mdna-games.com/cart.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

You can also put "lc=US" in the "Advanced Variables" section when you edit the hosted button on PayPal.com

For more details, see the locale list under [HTML Variables for PayPal Payments Standard](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables)